# date value to date format in R

Tags: r, as.date

i am trying to change the format of date that i import it from a CSV file. class for the date column is factor but when i want to use "as.Date" function it make me an error that the string format is not proper.

```
> New_His_data$BirthDate[1]
[1] 36473
1378 Levels: 13-1-1990 13-1-1991 13-10-1959 13-10-1973 13-10-1979 13-10-1988 13-10-1989 13-10-1994 13-11-1963 13-11-1970 ... 36473
> as.Date(New_His_data$BirthDate[1],origin = "1899-12-30")
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
> as.Date(strptime(New_His_data$BirthDate[1],"%d-%m-%Y"),origin ="1899-12-30")
[1] NA
```

when i use the value as number it work properly

```
> as.Date(36473,origin = "1899-12-30")
[1] "1999-11-09"
```

i tried to find some post regarding this issue but i could find nothing, please kindly help me with a solution or a link for a solution
thank you

Comment: this has to do with str/numeric values and how they are interpreted by the `as.Date()` function. 
 Please try `as.Date(as.numeric(New_His_data$BirthDate[1]),origin = "1899-12-30")`

Comment: it work but the value is not really the same, the data is much behind the actual date

Comment: > as.Date(36473,origin = "1899-12-30")
[1] "1999-11-09"
> as.Date(as.numeric(New_His_data$BirthDate[1]),origin = "1899-12-30")
[1] "1903-10-09"

Comment: thank you for the comment, it help me to get an idea

Comment: As an example 1981-1-2 ≠ 1981-01-02... The zeros are important

Answer (score 0):

Your data came in as a `factor` variable, likely via `read.csv()` or related when not setting `StringsAsFactors=FALSE`.

Nothing that a conversion to character can not fix.  Mock example:

```
R> v <- factor(c("13-1-1990", "13-1-1991", "13-10-1959")) # your first three
R> v
[1] 13-1-1990  13-1-1991  13-10-1959
Levels: 13-1-1990 13-1-1991 13-10-1959
R> 
R> d <- as.Date(as.character(v), format="%d-%m-%Y")
R> d        ## key here were the as.character() and the correct format
[1] "1990-01-13" "1991-01-13" "1959-10-13"
R> 
R> class(d) ## these are now Date objects
[1] "Date"
R> 
R> d + 1    ## that we can compute with
[1] "1990-01-14" "1991-01-14" "1959-10-14"
R>
```

Answer (score 0):

i could solve the issue just with two convert of data type from date to string to number and then i used "as.Date" function to change the format.

```
> New_His_data$BirthDate[1]
[1] 36473
1378 Levels: 13-1-1990 13-1-1991 13-10-1959 13-10-1973 13-10-1979 13-10-1988 13-10-1989 13-10-1994 13-11-1963 13-11-1970 ... 36473
> as.Date(New_His_data$BirthDate[1],origin = "1899-12-30")
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
> as.Date(strptime(New_His_data$BirthDate[1],"%d-%m-%Y"),origin ="1899-12-30")
[1] NA
> as.Date(as.numeric(as.character(New_His_data$BirthDate[1])),origin = "1899-12-30")
[1] "1999-11-09"
```